# How to logout (Session timeout and logout) the application using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Is there any way to get logout(Session timeout and logout) the application using JavaScript(without any service call). I tried with below code, but unable logout and clear the session. Please suggest me.

```
window.setTimeout('checkIfContinue()', 1*60*1000);  //1 minute

function checkIfContinue()
{
    if(confirm("Do you want to continue?"))
    {
        window.setTimeout('checkIfContinue()', 1*60*1000);
    }
    else
    {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.location.reload(true);
    window.location.replace('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: First of All, Show the code how you are login the user. If you are using PHP Cookies then show the logout page code. Or some else.

Comment: Assuming the session data is held on the server side (as it is in most cases) then no, you would need to make a call to the remote server to end the session. If you're using authentication tokens with a short lifespan you could potentially just clear the token from the client cache, but this is not secure at all as the session will still exist on the server until the token expires.

Comment: If you are just set one flag which shows the user is login or not like you are storing users details/token into the LocalStorage?
Then just remove that details from localStorage when the user clicked on logout button.
And you have to check before calling any API that the user's details/token exist into you the localStorage or not if not exists then redirect the user to login page else call API.